# FuelPHPのORMの中間テーブルに別テーブルを結合してその別テーブルの値を取得したい。

Tags: php, fuelphp, orm

FuelPHPの中間テーブルを
↓のような関係のテーブルを想定しています。

Aテーブル(マスタ)

```
id, name, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

Bテーブル

```
id, a_id, c_id, created_at, updated,at, deleted_at
```

Cテーブル(マスタ)

```
id, name, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

C_IDをキーにして、Aに紐づくすべてのa.nameを取得したいと考えているのですが、
ORMをつかって取得することは可能でしょうか？

```
$orm_model = \Model\Bs::find('all',
            array(
                'select'  => 'a.name',
                'related' => array(
                    'a' => array(
                        'join_type' => 'left',
                    )
                ),
                'where' => array(
                    array('c_id', $c_id)
                )
            )
        );
```

色々調査してみましたが、↑のような書き方をするとa.nameがNULLで取得されます。
ORMを使ってa.nameを取得する方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決したので原因を書きます。FuelPHPのキャッシュの問題だったようです。
下のような条件で検索した場合

Bテーブル

```
id, a_id, c_id, created_at, updated,at, deleted_at 

$orm_model = \Model\Bs::find('all',
            array(
                'select'  => 'a_id',
                'where' => array(
                    array('id', $id)
                )
            )
        );
```

↑の条件でSQLを流すと
id, a_idに値は入りますが、
c_id, created_at, updated,at, deleted_at にはNULLが入ったデータが取得されます。
上のSQLを流した後に検索条件を変えないで、
取得する文言を変えたSQLを流そうとすると

```
$orm_model = \Model\Bs::find('all',
            array(
                'select'  => 'c_id',
                'where' => array(
                    array('id', $id)
                )
            )
        );
```

SQLは発行されずに、
id, a_idに値が入っており、c_id, created_at, updated,at, deleted_at にはNULLが入っているキャッシュからデータが取得されるので、
c_idはNULLが取得されるのでおかしな挙動をするようでした。

解決策はDBクラスのクエリビルダを使うことで回避しました。

Answer (score 1):

サブクエリ、もしくはカスタムSQLで対処するという選択ではダメでしょうか！？

http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/packages/orm/crud.html

あとは、FuelphpのDBクラスを使用して書くのもありかと思います。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/database/db.html